# Stop Rstudio while running long script (not just 1 line)

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

Cross posting this [from Rstudio](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-completely-interrupt-script-running-in-rstudio/76200) (I'm not the original author).

This is a persistent problem for me since updating Rstudio (v.1.3.952) where I feel I must be missing something.

Say you have the following script:

```
Sys.sleep(5)
Sys.sleep(5)
Sys.sleep(5)
Sys.sleep(5)
```

And you run with Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+Enter. You then decide you want stop the entire script (not just the current line/command), how do you do it?

Esc doesn't work because it only stops the current line.
Terminate doesn't work because it stops the entire R session and you'd have to reload packages.

Comment: I don't know an obvious way. You can wrap your whole script into `{ }`, one the first, one in the last line. Doing so, [ESC] stops the execution of the part in `{ }`, if you use [CTRL]+[A], [CTRL]+[Enter].

Comment: I don't think its possible

Comment: Martin Gal, that's a good idea. I hadn't thought of that.